# k8s external-ip SNAT?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I add one external ip `1.1.1.1` for one of my pod, and I can access pod's udp port `1234` via `1.1.1.1:1234` from external network, but I found that k8s do SNAT for the request and from my pod, the source ip is k8s's ip `10.244.0.1:1234`. When my pod response udp pkt to `10.244.0.1:1234`, k8s does not do DNAT for me, so external network can not receive response at all. What ip and port should my pod response? Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need an explicit DNAT rule since there is a conntrack table created for the SNAT rule which has the 4-tuple(src ip, dst ip, src port, dst port) to identify a connection for the response packets. Do you send multiple udp requests with the same 4-tuple, I do remember there is a conntrack table condition race for udp since it is connection-less.

Comment: Yes You are right. I make a mistake

Comment: @HangDu Could you please consider posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @OhHiMark Sure thing, just not sure whether it resolves the question.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an explicit DNAT rule since there is a conntrack table created for the SNAT rule which has the 4-tuple(src ip, dst ip, src port, dst port) to identify a connection for the response packets. Do you send multiple udp requests with the same 4-tuple, I do remember there is a conntract table race condition for udp. You can take a look at the details of the race condition from the following [link](https://www.weave.works/blog/racy-conntrack-and-dns-lookup-timeouts).